# Is this use of 'in the first place' correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

In [an answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5715/how-do-i-expand-my-vocabulary#:%7E:text=Practice%20using%20new%20words%20in%20conversation.%20You%20can%20try%20this%20with%20a%20native%20speaker%20or%20someone%20who%20has%20more%20experience%20than%20you.%20This%20is%20especially%20important%20if%20you%20rarely%20speak%20English%20in%20the%20first%20place.) in *Meta* by *DialFrost*, he gave a piece of advice on how to expand English vocabulary,

> Practice using new words in conversation. You can try this with a native speaker or someone who has more experience than you. This is especially important if you rarely speak English **in the first place**.

'*In the first place*' above sounds like 'given that' or 'now that'. That is, the sentence can be reworded as

> This is especially important given you rarely speak English.

But *dictionary.com* gives as *in the first place*'s [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-the-first-place):

> 1. From the beginning, at the outset, before anything else.
> 2. As the first of several items in order of importance. This phrase is usually accompanied by in the second place, third place, and so on.

DialFrost's use of it matches neither of the given meanings. Is his/her use of 'in the first place' actually incorrect?

Note: The OP of that question said he/she rarely spoke (it's *speak* when he/she asked the question) English in his/her question. So, it's a known fact to DialFrost.

Comment: I don't agree with your rewording here - if I were to reword it, I'd probably simply replace the "in the first place" with "anyway" - "This is especially important if you rarely speak English anyway" - or leave it out entirely. Your rewording changes the meaning entirely by losing the conditional.

Comment: @Showsni How can I **lose conditional** by using *'given'* which means '[considering a particular thing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/given#:~:text=considering%20a%20particular%20thing)'?

Comment: @Michael "given that" and "if" are not at all the same. "Given that X" means *X is true*. "If X, ..." means *it's possible that X is true*. In your case here, DialFrost doesn't know if the reader rarely speaks English, so they used "if". "Given that you rarely speak English" means, "Because you rarely speak English, ..."

Comment: @gotube That OP said so in his/her question. So, it's a known fact to DialFrost.

Comment: Ah. The problem then is that "given" replaces "if", not "in the first place". You can still add it to your rephrasing: "*This is especially important given you rarely speak English **in the first place**.*" So your rephrasing doesn't affect your question about the phrase, "in the first place".

Comment: Showsni got it right in their comment above when they said in that context, "in the first place" has the same function as "anyway", and doesn't have any logical meaning about an earlier time.

Comment: The phrase doesn't add anything to the meaning of "...if you rarely speak English...*.

Answer (score 1):

It matches the first meaning, although it's not obvious - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20first%20place) has a more precise definition of that usage:

> —used at the end of a sentence to indicate what was true or what should have been done at the beginning of a situation
>
> *We should never have gone there in the first place.*
>
> *I didn't care much for the job in the first place.*

So one way to explain the meaning is that there's an issue X (for example, "I lost my job", "we got lost in the woods", "I need to speak English more often"), but there's also a broader issue Y that encompasses X ("I never liked that job", "we shouldn't have gone there", "I rarely speak English").

In your specific case *in the first place* is rather unnecessary, but not wrong - it's used more for emphasis, to indicate that the dedicated practice is important in all cases, but it's *especially* important if you *already* rarely get to speak English.

Comment: I don't see how this definition fits here. This definition obviously means something should happen preceding in time. But DialFrost was talking about that OP's situation.

Comment: By the way, 'I never liked that job' does not encompass 'I lost my job'- they are two things. So are your other example.

Comment: But you would say it if you were no longer in that job, or were soon to leave it.

Comment: @KateBunting But that does not meet the definition in dictionaries. Dunno if his use is some kind of language bending.